# Add new column at nth position Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, multiple-columns

I am trying to dynamically add a new column at nth position. Currently, please find below my code.

```
var name = window.prompt("Please enter the Column Name you intend to Add", "");
var name2 = window.prompt("Please enter the Column Location you intend to Add", "");
if (name == null || name.trim() == "" || name == "0") {
    alert('Invalid Column Number');
}
else if (name2 == null || name2.trim() == "" || name2 == "0") {
    alert('Invalid Column Number');
}
else {
    var name1 = parseInt(name2);
    $('td:nth-child(' + name1 + ')').append($("<td>"));
    $('th:nth-child(' + name1 + ')').html(name).css("font-weight", "Bold");     
}
```

HTML Mark-Up

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top:10px;">
              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">
                 <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th>Sl No</th>
                       <th>Item Id</th>
                       <th>Item Description</th>
                       <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                    <tr id="mainid">
                       <td><input type="text"/></td>
                       <td><input type="text"/></td>
                       <td><input type="text"/></td>
                       <td><input type="text"/></td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
              </table>
           </div>
```

I am able to successfully add the new column, but this is replacing the existing one. What i need is to append to index numbered column but, its replacing it. Can anyone please guide to resolve this.

Comment: can you post the markup?

Comment: Add the markup mate!

Comment: What values do you pass in `name1`?

Comment: name has the column name and name2 has the column index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert it `before` the `td` you found on index, not append

```
 $('td:nth-child(' + name1 + ')').insertBefore($("<td>"));
```

You are appending the `td` which will actually add the `td` as the child of found `td` and not as sibling

**One suggestion as well**

I also think that you should run this line as well to add the header for your new column

```
$('th:nth-child(' + name1 + ')').insertBefore($("<th>"));
```